# How to mix react-md and material-ui components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to mix react-md and material-ui components?
I'm trying to use componenets from both libraries, but they override the styles from each other.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- i dont think think thats an good  idea , beacuse i have tried the same ,initially it works fine but when you want to add more styles, or try to customise  it ran into errors, styles collide with each other and you wont get desired result.
- and it will also gives problem in server side rendering.
- if  react-md or material ui standalone not fullfilling your requirements than you can also take look at [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/)